# How to select polygons which are situated between two points using select by location?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, select-by-location

I am working with ArcMap 10.3. and have a polygon layer and a point layer. I've selected two point layers and now I want to select the polygons which are situated between those two points. Is there a chance how I can do that with "select by location"?

Comment: The Select Features menu is normally Select by Rectangle but has Select by Line option. You can draw a line from Point to Point to select all Polygons crossing that line.

Answer (score 1):

From klewis - in comments:

> The Select Features menu is normally Select by Rectangle but has
>   Select by Line option. You can draw a line from Point to Point to
>   select all Polygons crossing that line.